# Update new field in Mapper. Jhipster 4.4.1

Tags: jhipster

In proyect with Jhipste 4.4.1, Spring Boot, Grandle, MongoDb

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {})
public interface OportunidadMapper extends EntityMapper <OportunidadDTO,    Oportunidad> {
```

Is OportunidadDTO ad:

```
private Long clienteId;
```

In Oportunidad

```
@Field("clienteId")
private Long clienteId;
```

I added a field to the DTO and to the entity but the Mapper does not parse it to me. Do I have to do something else, so that I can recognize it? (They have getter and setter in both classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must recompile your project with gradle so that MapStruct annotation processor re-generates OportunidadMapperImpl class.

Comment: I was doing it since Eclipse and that's why I was not doing well. Thank you very much.